# http Referer, Custom domain & CORS in OCI Object Storage

Tags: http-referer, domain-name, object-storage, hotlinking, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am new to OCI Object Storage (not the object storage classic) and I have hard time figuring out how things works. I couldn't find anything in documents about

1) How to setup custom domain for buckets?

2) How to prevent hotlinking (http referer)?

3) How do I allow Cross-Domain Resource Sharing with CORS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, OCI Object Storage does not currently support this functionality. It may be possible to perform these functions using a CDN with an Object Storage bucket as the origin, but it is not directly possible in Object Storage.

hope you are well
tim